# is there any way to redirect callback url in ruby on rails from module (not controller)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I am working on facebook graph API to refresh the user access token because Facebook refreshes access token on every 60 days (if the token is long lived) and I have written code inside a module because I need to refresh the token before it expires so and I need to run this method from background worker or job, If my code running from controller then, in this case, no problem because I am able to redirect the Facebook auth URL (callback URL) by using redirect_to but when I am running it from Worker or module it throws error for redirect_to method because `redirect_to` method not available to modules (If I am try to use get and post request from Httparty or Net modules then its send request to the facebook auth url but the request not back to my controller but If i hit the url from browser then the request comes back to my combtroller )below is my module code:-

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(Figaro.env.fb_app_id,Figaro.env.fb_secret_token,Figaro.env.fb_callback_url)

oauth_code_url = @oauth.url_for_oauth_code

redirect_to oauth_code_url
```

This code is fine for the controller but not for the module? and I know MVC architecture and request/response is done through controller but my need is to just redirect the  Facebook OAuth URL so that I can get the code from Facebook and then refresh the token. I have also tried HttpClient but it also not worked `redirect_uri_callback=(redirect_uri_callback) ⇒ Object` http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/HTTPClient:redirect_uri_callback= so now what should I do?

Comment: You need the user to visit your app again to create a fresh short-lived user token first.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value of `self` from the controller action to the module (note I changed it to a class method for simplicity)

```
module FacebookStuff
  def self.handle_oauth_request(request)
    @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(
      Figaro.env.fb_app_id,Figaro.env.fb_secret_token,Figaro.env.fb_callback_url
    )
    oauth_code_url = @oauth.url_for_oauth_code
    request.redirect_to oauth_code_url
  end
end

# in controller action
FacebookStuff.handle_oauth_request(self)
```

or you could keep the module method the way it is and just move the last line to the controller. Have the module method return the oauth_code_url and then use that in the controller action to redirect. Both should work and it's kind of up to you which you use. A third option would be to move the method from the module to ApplicationController, the methods of which are available to all controllers. A fourth option would be to `include` the module into the controller.

Comment: can I call this method from the worker or background jobs?

Comment: It depends on whether you keep the request-handling logic internal or not. In other words, if you call redirect_to outside of the module (and thus it doesn't require to be inside the request/response lifecycle), then you can use the module in any circumstance presumptively.

Comment: actually I am calling this from a worker and its giving error that `undefined method `redirect_to' `

Comment: that's exactly the point i was trying to make. If you make it depend on a request object, it will not be able to get called from anywhere except a controller. That's why you should extract the redirect_to to the caller scope. It doesn't really make sense for the worker to call redirect_to anyway, does it?

Comment: I got your point about request object, but your last line I am not getting you should extract the redirect_to to the caller scope?? here caller is a worker that's why I am little bit confused? sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: If you don't need redirect_to (i.e. from a worker) then don't use it. You can still call it from the controller.